# Simplifying this function: $\ddot x=\frac{l\sin(t)-\sin(\sin(t))g}{\cos(\sin(t))}$ .

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How to simplify this? (only the right side)

$$\ddot x=\frac{l\sin(t)-\sin(\sin(t))g}{\cos(\sin(t))}$$

$\ddot x$ is a function of $t$
$l$ and $g$ are constants.

Comment: RHS$=l\tan(t)-g\tan(\sin(t))$?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb what is RHS?

Comment: it means the Right Hand Side of the equation